# How to create virtual table FTS with external sqlite content table?

Tags: sqlite, fts4

I want to create a SQLite virtual table with a content of a real one.

I have a small sample which demonstrates my problem. I already red the official tutorial, but can't find anything wrong in this code. Some users use a `rebuild` option, but it doesn't work for me.

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS posts (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);  
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO posts (a) VALUES(510000);  
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO posts (a) VALUES(510001);  
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO posts (a) VALUES(510300);  
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts_fts using fts5(content=posts, content_rowid=a, a);  

SELECT * FROM posts_fts where posts_fts MATCH '10' ORDER BY a ASC;
```

If I run this, I get:

```
0 rows returned in 2ms from: SELECT * FROM posts_fts where posts_fts match '10' ORDER BY a ASC;
```

Does anyone have an idea wat I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"10" is not a token in the FTS table.

From [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#tokenizers):

> **4.3.1. Unicode61 Tokenizer**
>
> The unicode tokenizer classifies all unicode characters as either
> "separator" or "token" characters. By default all space and
> punctuation characters, as defined by Unicode 6.1, are considered
> separators, and all other characters as token characters. More
> specifically, all unicode characters assigned to a general category
> beginning with "L" or "N" (letters and numbers, specifically) or to
> category "Co" ("other, private use") are considered tokens. All other
> characters are separators.
>
> Each contiguous run of one or more token characters is considered to
> be a token. The tokenizer is case-insensitive according to the rules
> defined by Unicode 6.1.

Also from [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax):

> **3.2. FTS5 Phrases**
>
> FTS queries are made up of phrases. A phrase is an ordered list of one
> or more tokens.

You might try a "prefix query"  i.e. `MATCH "5*"` to see that you get results.

Comment: Thanks @DinoCoderSaurus! I tried to match with 'prefix', but it does't work. Did you try to run this code with other `match` expressions? It creates a virtual table with the content of real one, but you can't match anything. I also worked with other builtin tokenizers with the same result.

Comment: Do an integrity check `insert into posts_fts(posts_fts) VALUES ('integrity-check');` If it returns errors, rebuild `insert into posts_fts(posts_fts) VALUES ('rebuild');`. I ran your script on an in-memory database from SQLite command line (version 3.17.0). `validity-check` gave `Error: database disk image is malformed`. After rebuild, the prefix query worked.

Comment: Now it works after update to SQLite version 3.27.2 and it works after `rebuild`. It's still a mystery why this issue occurs.